# What is the instrument played on the holodeck in Paris?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *Star Trek: TNG*, S1 E23 "We'll Always Have Paris", there is a man on the holodeck who appears to be slowly fondling some glass tubes in such a way as to produce music. What is this bizarre instrument being played in the Paris simulation? Does it have a name in-universe, or has it appeared elsewhere?

[image: Bongamaphone]

Comment: It looks like, umm, a glass bagpipe kazoo.

Comment: @anaranjada I was thinking Bongamaphone but yes, agreed

Comment: If it was our past or present, a concertina would not be out of place. Since this is the future, perhaps a futuristic extrapolation of a concertina.

Comment: This is the doobie-matic 2000

Comment: Whoa - let's attach a NSFW warning on the picture. ;-)

Comment: @Valorum I was going to say an array of, ahem, vacuum pumps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_musical_instruments#Caf.C3.A9_des_Artistes_instrument) simply calls it the Café des Artistes instrument. It apparently never appeared in any other episodes.

None of the instruments listed on [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Musical_instruments) appear to be the same instrument.